# Mocha.js : cannot run more than 10 files in parallel mode

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm using '--parallel' flag in mocha command to run files in parallel.
But if input 15 tests files, there could only run 10 files in parallel mode and the other 5 files will be start after the fist 10 files finished.
How can i run more than 10 test files in parallel with mocha.js?

```
mocha -p -b -r should 'file1 path' 'file2 path'...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocha 8 offers the option [`-j` or `--jobs`](https://mochajs.org/#-jobs-count-j-count) to specify the number of tests to be run at the same time, e.g.

```
mocha -j 20 -p -b -r should 'file1 path' 'file2 path'...
```